# Is it possible to create a new hook after creating the model?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Elsewhere in the doc using mongoose.model ('MyModel').Schema

So for example, I have this code:

```
const UsuarioSchema = mongoose.model('MyModel').schema

UsuarioSchema.pre('save', ( next) => {
  console.log('working')
  next()        
})
```

But is not inside of `my_model.js`. It's possible to do this?

## Update

I found in the documentation that it is not possible to add a hook after compiling the model, which is what I was doing.

> ### [Define Middleware Before Compiling Models](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#defining)
>
> Calling pre() or post() after compiling a model does not work in Mongoose in general. For example, the below pre('save') middleware will not fire.

Comment: sure, why not? it doesn't matter which file it is in. Does it not work?

Comment: I can't get the event to fire

Comment: can you post a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: It will not be needed, I found in the documentation that it is not possible to add a hook after compiling the model, which is what I was doing.

Comment: great! I recommend posting your update as an answer instead, so people know the question is answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found in the documentation that it is not possible to add a hook after compiling the model, which is what I was doing.

> ### [Define Middleware Before Compiling Models](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#defining)
>
> Calling pre() or post() after compiling a model does not work in Mongoose in general. For example, the below pre('save') middleware will not fire.